# datatables ajax cannot read json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I'm trying to pull data via url. The data in the url looks as follows. I guess I can't read because of the \ and " signs. How can I overcome this?

The error I get is as follows

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'length')

```js
$('#papara-invest').DataTable({
        ajax:{url:"test.json",type: "GET",dataSrc:"data"},
        colReorder: true,
        stateSave: true,
        dom: 'Bfrtip'
})
```

The json data generated when you enter the connection appears as follows.

```
"{\"data\":[{ \"ID\": 415974, \"userName\": \"johanna6060\", \"amount\": 11, \"userId\": \"johanna6060\", \"name\": \"johanna6060\", \"processId\": \"johanna6060\", \"trackingId\": \"companyname\", \"time\": \"johanna6060\"}]}"
```

Comment: Use JSON.parse() to convert your result to json which is a string in this case

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write `"datatype": 'json'` in request.

```
ajax:{url:"test.json",type: "GET",dataSrc:"data", datatype": 'json'}
```